# GridView - How to make a link from a value in a grid to a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and would like that when someone clicks a value in the grid, for it to run a function.

I have seen buttons

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnInfo" runat="server" OnClientClick="populateLabel()" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MoreInfo"
  Text="More Info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strID") %>'/>
```

But I don't really need a button, I want the value of the result to be clickable. As far as I can see, you can't bind the value of a button to a data element?

Comment: absolutely unclear, please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass the eval value to a javascript function.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInfo" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("populateLabel(''{0}'')", Eval("strID"));  %>' CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MoreInfo"
  Text="More Info" />
```

You can also just use a regular ole anchor tag instead of a server control

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='<%# String.Format("populateLabel(''{0}'')", Eval("strID"));  %>'>More Info</a>
```

Comment: Perfect, in the end I went with <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USERID">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkCustDetails" Text='<%# Eval("USERNAME") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("LOOKUP_ID") %>'  OnClick="displayMoreInfo" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>